# What are the homology groups $H_k(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\})$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Is there an easy way to calculate the homology groups

$$H_k(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}), k\geq 0$$

I was able to calculate $H_k(\mathbb{R}^m\setminus \{0\}), m > 1$ because we have a homeomorphism onto the sphere $S^{m-1}$ whose homology groups I know, but we do not have $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \cong S^0 = \{-1,1\}$ so for $m=1$ this approach fails.

Of course, $H_0(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ since there are two path components.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb R\backslash \{0\}\simeq (-\infty,0)\sqcup (0,\infty)$. Hence, $H_k(\Bbb R\backslash \{0\})=H_k(-\infty,0)\oplus H_k(0,\infty)=0\oplus 0$ text for $k>0$. As convex sets are contractible.

Comment: Let $m=1$? Anyway $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent (not  homeomorphic) to two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ deformation retracts to two discrete points.

Also, $\mathbb{R}^m\backslash\{0\}$ is *not* homeomorphic to a sphere (again, deformation retract).

Comment: How is $\mathbb{R}^m \setminus \{0\}$ not homeomorphic to the sphere? Don't we have $\mathbb{R}^m \setminus \{(0, \dots, 0,1\}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere via stereographic projection?

Comment: @user745578 $\Bbb R^m\backslash\{0\}$ is non-compact, but sphere is always is compact. So, $\Bbb R^m\backslash\{0\}$ is not homeomorphic to sphere as continuous image of a compact set is compact.  But $\Bbb S^m-\{\text{North pole}\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^m$ via stereographic projection.